# Yum: xz compression not available on Fedora 12

Tags: fedora, yum, fedora-12, xz

I am currently in the process of updating an old Fedora server, and am currently on Fedora 12. on the last update I forgot to upgrade rpm ([see here](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Upgrading_from_EOL_Fedora_using_yum#Fedora_11_-.3E_Fedora_12)). Now yum always returns this error: `Error: xz compression not available`. Any ideas on what to install to get yum functioning again?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that I was missing `pyliblzma`. Don't install it by switching to the epel-release though. just run this instead to install pyliblzma:

```
    rpm -Uhv http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/i386/pyliblzma-0.5.3-3.el6.i686.rpm
```